# Android setText is taking too long

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity

Hi I have this piece of code:

```
editText.setOnEditorActionListener(new OnEditorActionListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
        boolean handled = false;
        morseText = editText.getText().toString();
        message.setText("Sending Message...");
        message.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
        sendMessage();

        return handled;
    }
});
```

Everything works as expected except that setText and setTextColor are taking effect after sendMessage() has already finished, and for the record sendMessage() might take a few seconds.
I need the text to change before sendMessage.

How can I solve this and why this is happening?
Thank you

Comment: try to use Handler post delay for running sendMessage().

Comment: How about running sendMessage() in seperate handler?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> setText and setTextColor are taking effect after sendMessage() has already finished

They will not take effect until you return control of the main application thread to the framework, when `onEditorAction()` returns.

> for the record sendMessage() might take a few seconds

Then that work has to be done on a background thread.

> How can I solve this

Move any work that will take longer than ~1ms off of the main application thread and onto background threads. You may wish to read more about [Android's threading model](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html#Threads).

Answer (score 0):

try this code to run sendMessage():

```
new Handler().post(new Runnable(){
    public void run(){
        sendMessage();
    }
});
```

or use postDelay to replace post.

Answer (score 0):

Delay the `sendMessage` after the UI been given a chance to draw your changes. Also if `sendMessage` takes seconds of time, consider putting it on IO thread.

```
    TextView editText = null;
    assert editText != null;
    editText.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
            boolean handled = false;
            morseText = editText.getText().toString();
            message.setText("Sending Message...");
            message.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
            v.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    sendMessage();
                }
            }, 1);
            return handled;
        }
    });
```